# Cant unmarshall dynamodb attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-go

I'm experimenting with AWS-SDK-GO with the DynamoDB API...

I'm trying to query the db and return a string. But I'm having some issues  unmarshelling the return value....

struct

```
type Item struct {
     slug string
     destination string
}
```

query function

```
input := &dynamodb.GetItemInput{
    Key: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
        "slug": {
            S: aws.String(slug),
        },
    },
    TableName: db.TableName,
}

result, err := db.dynamo.GetItem(input)
if err != nil {
    return "",  err
}

n := Item{}
err = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(result.Item, &n)

if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Failed to unmarshal Record, %v", err)
    return "", err
}
log.Printf("dump %+v", n)
log.Printf("echo %s", n.slug)
log.Printf("echo %s", n.destination)
log.Printf("orig %v", result.Item)
```

result

```
2017/10/11 14:21:34 dump {slug: destination:}
2017/10/11 14:21:34 echo 
2017/10/11 14:21:34 echo 
2017/10/11 14:21:34 orig map[destination:{
  S: "http://example.com"
} slug:{
  S: "abcde"
}]
```

Why is Item being returned empty?

I've tried to look everywhere but find no solution....

Comment: what is the data type of attribute destination in dynamodb table?

Comment: String both of them, like the struct

Comment: Did you try the below solution?

Comment: if you want to [Unmarshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) an `Item` instance you have to make public its attributes, just make first letter as upper case for each attribute

Comment: whats it for sdk v2 - any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whether you have tried this. I think if you can change the struct as mentioned below, it may resolve the problem.

I assumed that both `slug` and `destination` are defined/saved as String attribute in DynamoDB table.

```
type Item struct {
     Slug string`json:"slug"`
     Destination string`json:"destination"`
}
```

Change the print to:-

```
log.Printf("echo %s", n.Slug)
log.Printf("echo %s", n.Destination)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue and seems to be related, unmarsheling a specific attribute of the struct seems to do it.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/850

Example

```
var item Item
if err = dynamodbattribute.Unmarshal(result.Item["destination"], &item.destination); err != nil {
    log.Printf("UnmarshalMap(GetItem response) err=%q", err)
}
```